# インストールした外部ライブラリが import 出来ない

Tags: python, python3, pandas

Pythonでcsvを読み込んで加工して分析みたいなことをしたいと思って、
Python3.7とpycharmをインストールしました。

csvの読み込みにはpandasだと記事で読んだので、まずpandasを入れてインポートしようとしたのですができず・・・具体的には以下です。

ターミナルで`pip show pandas`と実行したら、以下が出てきたのでインストールはできているんだと思います。

```
Name: pandas
Version: 0.25.1
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: http://pandas.pydata.org
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by: seaborn
```

しかし、Pythonで`import pandas as pd`と入力しても、以下のエラーが返されてしまいます。

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

似ている質問はあるが解決できませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

確証はないですがpycharmに元から入っているpythonを使用しているのが原因かもしれません．
質問された方が、pycharmとpythonを別々にインストールしたのであれば，インストールしたpythonをpycharmで使えるようにしてあげれば大丈夫かと思います．

変更する方法としては

```
File -> Setting -> Project Interpreter
```

まで開き，右の方にある歯車マークを押してAddを選択します．
Base interpreterの横の...マークを開き，インストールしたpythonのパスを指定してやれば完了です．

もし変更がめんどくさいのであれば，Project interpreterの画面の横にある十マークを押してやって，フォームにpandasと入力すると色々出てくると思うので，ほしいパッケージを選択してinstall packageを押すと，pycharm既存のpythonにpandasをインストールできます．

Answer (score 1):

原因を調べる手順を考えました。よろしければお試しください。

(１）スクリプトに以下のコードを追加して、sys.pathの内容を調べます。

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

(２）表示された内容にpandasのパス名が含まれているかを確認し、
　含まれていない場合は以下のコードを追加して現象が再現されるかを確認します。

```
sys.path.append("pandasのパス")
```

(２）現象が再現しない場合は、設定ファイルにpandasのパスを追加すればOK(のはず)です。
　※　設定ファイルはツールに依存していますので、具体的におこたえすることができません。

Answer (score 1):

下記で、anacondaとなってますよね。
（抜粋）Location: /Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
さらに、Pycharmですよね。
かなり、ややこしいと思います。
anacondaならanaconda、PycharmならPycharmのみ、みたいにされるのが、
無難だと思います。
pipとかcondaとか、モジュール管理ツールがいろんなことをするし、
どこに何がインストールされて、それが、どこで有効になるか、わかりにくいと思います。

慣れるまでは、
ひとつの環境のみにのる、のがいいと思います。